# Custom button to show sidebar Material Design Lite

Tags: angular, material-design, sidebar

I'm creating an app using the Angular 2 and MDL using maps, and I'm doing a similar component, replacing the header, to the official site maps.google.com. I wanted to create a custom button to display the lateral sidebar MDL.

[image: Custom header component]

How do this: I click the own button to show the sidebar on the left?

(I do not know if I was clear on the question)

**EDIT1**
Works fine:

```
  ...
  constructor(){
    // for fix "MaterialLayout not found"
    let MaterialLayout:any;
    this.drawer = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout');
  }

  toogleDrawer(){
    this.drawer.MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer();
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with:

```
export class MapHeaderBadget{
 constructor(){
    // for fix "MaterialLayout not found"
    let MaterialLayout:any;
    this.drawer = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout');
  }
  // icon click event
  toogleDrawer(){
    this.drawer.MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer();
  }
}
```